# Realm Encrypted cause insert very slow in Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm testing performance of realm in Android.
if I insert 10000 data in non-encryted realm, it costs 16184ms, while it cost 36000ms with encryted realm.it is too slow!
Does encryption cause this situation？ how to solve this problem？

*SQLite Code：*

```
            ArrayList<ContentValues> valueArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
            ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
            value.put(PersonInfoTableEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DISPLAYINFO, list.get(i).getDisplayInfo());
            value.put(PersonInfoTableEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DISPLAYPIC, list.get(i).getDisplayPic());
            value.put(PersonInfoTableEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DISPLAYVERSION, list.get(i).getDisplayVersion());
            value.put(PersonInfoTableEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FEATURE, list.get(i).getFaceFeatures());
            value.put(PersonInfoTableEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FEATUREVERSION, list.get(i).getFeatureVersion());
            value.put(PersonInfoTableEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PEOPLEVERSION, list.get(i).getPeopleVersion());
            value.put(PersonInfoTableEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMPS, list.get(i).getTimestamp());
            value.put(PersonInfoTableEntry.COLUMN_NAME_META, list.get(i).getMeta());
            valueArray.add(value);
        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e(TAG, "StartTime Batch: " + "[" + number + "] " + startTime);
        db.beginTransaction();
        for (ContentValues contentValue: valueArray) {
            long newRowId = db.insert(PersonInfoTableEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValue);
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e(TAG, "EndTime Batch: " + "[" + number + "] " + endTime);
        String str = "BatchWriteWithoutEncrypt [" + number + "] cost time : " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms";
        Log.e(TAG, str);
```

*Realm Code:*

```
        ArrayList<PersonInfo> list = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
            PersonInfo tmpPersonInfo = new PersonInfo();
            tmpPersonInfo.setDisplayInfo("测试" + rand.nextInt());
            tmpPersonInfo.setDisplayPic(disPic + rand.nextInt());
            RealmList<String> tmpStrList = new RealmList<>();
            tmpStrList.add(featureStr);
            tmpPersonInfo.setFaceFeatures(tmpStrList);
            tmpPersonInfo.setDisplayVersion(md5);
            tmpPersonInfo.setFeatureVersion(md5);
            tmpPersonInfo.setMeta(md5);
            list.add(tmpPersonInfo);
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"Array size is " + list.size());

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e(TAG, "StartTime Batch: " + "[" + number + "] " + startTime);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.insert(list);
        realm.commitTransaction();

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e(TAG, "EndTime Batch: " + "[" + number + "] " + endTime);
        String str = "BatchWriteWithoutEncrypt [" + number + "] cost time : " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms";
        Log.e(TAG, str);
```

Comment: Transaction code

Comment: Please share your database insertion code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your below code

```
 long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.e(TAG, "StartTime Batch: " + "[" + number + "] " + startTime);
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.insert(list);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

with this

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()){
        realm.executeTransaction( rlm -> rlm.insert(list));
        // OR i'd suggest to go for async transaction
        realm.executeTransactionAsync( rlm -> rlm.insert(list));
}
```